# How to display country, state and city dependency in Angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to display the country in response from dropdown. I tried a lot and I could not find any solution.

I am using a JavaScript link "http://iamrohit.in/lab/js/location.js".

I am getting the selected country name from JSON response but can't compare it with the dropdown list and display the response value.

**My HTML :**

```
<select name="country" class="form-control1 drop countries" required  ng-model="model.country" placeholder="select" id="countryId sel1"><option value="" disabled selected>Select</option>
```

**My controller :**

```
$scope.model.country = "India"; //from json response
```

I saw this "**`<option value="? string:India ?"></option>`**" when I inspect the country field in the profile page.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to view what option is selected, the you will indeed put your ng-model in your  tag. 
But if I understand correctly, you want to  create different options according to your JSON data. 
I suggest using:

```
    <select>
      <div ng-repeat= "x in model.country">
        <option> {{x.Name}} </option> //I suggest dividing your JSON information
      </div>
    </select>
```

I hope this answers your questions. Let me know if you need more precise information!

Comment: Thanks but why i need to use ng-repeat. I want to match my json response, "country" : "USA" with the dropdown. If this value exist in the dropdown then i need to display it as the selected value.

Comment: Hi @kalai, to achieve this simply:

Comment: compare each of your options (with ng-models) in your controller, using an array.